# What are .mvfs_*** files in clearcase folder?

Tags: clearcase

When ever I make a change, an `.mvfs_xxxx` file gets created in my ClearCase folder.
I've a dynamic view.

I tried to remove these files and my system always get stuck.

What is the purpose of this file and how can I control MVFS from creating files in my clearcase folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[About dot files in the view storage](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21149499)"

#### `.mvfsxxxxxx` files

> Q: There are also files named `.mvfsxxxxxxx` in my view. They show up as view private files when I run `cleartool lsprivate` in my dynamic view. How did they get there and can I delete them?
>
> A: **These are files that were removed when another process still had them open**.
>   In order to allow the open process to continue reading the file after the file has been removed (UNIX semantics) the original file is renamed to some temporary unique name (just as in NFS).
>
> The `.MVFS` files can be deleted using standard operating system remove commands (`rm` or `del`).

```
Example: cleartool lsprivate | fgrep '.mvfs' | rm"
```

In your case, a reboot might be in order before starting just the dynamic view and trying to remove them (without launching any other processes).

---

Apprently, (from [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=198255)), they are called "**silly renames**":

> has anyone ever seen view private files called something like

```
.mvfs_47e21162
```

> > with 0 byte size?
>
> It is what is called a silly-renamed file.
>   You get these in the MVFS if you delete a file while someone has it open.
>
> In local filesystems deleting an open file causes the name to go away but the data is maintained in memory. On a distributed filesystem like the MVFS or NFS this doesn't work because the actual file is on a different system.
>   Both the MVFS and the NFS get around this problem by renaming the file to something "silly"
>   that is normally invisible and is unlikely to cause a naming conflict.

You get those also with [ClearCase Multisite](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21579575) (for a different reason), where the term "silly rename" is (this time officially) mentioned.

Comment: The `.mvfs`-files are by the way similar to files deleted on NFS that ends up as `.nfs`-files.

Comment: @hlovdal I believe the last link in my answer (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21579575) says just what you mention.

Comment: So I created a new view and I see these files being created again and not 0 bytes. mostly 1 ~ 5 Kb files and it doesn't delete well, even by the command in VonC's post

Comment: @bMathew what ClearCase version do you use? On which OS?

Comment: ClearCase version 7.0.1 (Thu May 17 09:19:01 2007)
    ClearCase version 7.0.1_iFix01 (Wed Sep 19 11:15:35 2007)
    ClearCase version 7.0.1.1 (Wed Nov 28 17:43:24 2007)
    ClearCase version 7.0.1.1_iFix01 (Tue Feb 12 10:48:57 2008)
    ClearCase version 7.0.1.1_iFix02 (Wed May 14 23:53:33 2008)
    ClearCase version 7.0.1.2 (Fri Jul 18 12:43:48 2008)
    @(#) MVFS version 7.0.1.2 (Fri May 16 03:38:33 2008)
    cleartool              7.0.1.2 (Thu Jun 19 03:18:09  2008)
    db_server     7.0.1.2 (Sat Jun 14 04:10:45 2008)
    VOB database schema version: 54

Comment: @bMathew In that case, you might need to apply an hotfix to your Clearcase client (and ideally server, but just patching the client should be enough in your case): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK54038